# [Rails]how can i save multiple record in new from when i use scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold, multiple-records

if i make one scaffold code like this

```
rails g scaffold Order name:string item:string
rake db:migrate
```

then in 'app/views/orders/_form.html.erb' there is form for one record of Order model

and in orders_controller.rb

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
end
```

but i want to get multiple record for Order in one form

how can i do this? I tried

```
def new
  @orders = []
  4.times do
     @orders << Order.new
  end
end
```

but after this code i cannot do anything...can anyone help me please

Comment: Well, you are on a good track, but a lot more needs to be done (and out of scope for a SO question). I recommend going through [this](http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2015/07/18/create-multiple-objects-from-single-form-in-rails/) tutorial and then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: yes i already read that post, but that writer just use Model, and i want use Scaffold. I'm confusing that form_for in scaffold and form_tag for model

Comment: The reason behind changing `form_for` to `form_tag` is to have flexibility for setting order params as an array. You can still use `form_for`, but you will need do more configuration in your controller

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does form_tag  more effective in this case?

Comment: Yes, i prefer `form_tag`  (for this specific case) since is a generic tag, which allows to send params as an array. At the end both are just helpers that will render out a ´form´, so either one will work. `form_for` is simpler for more standard (i.e. 1 object) scenarios.

Comment: I really appreciate your  kind reply!! i'll try! Thanks